# Show label value description text in change screen

Tags: gerrit

I would like to show the label value description text right after the value in the labels and votes area in the change screen

E.g. for the label "Verified" the value description text for -1 is "Fails". In the label and votes area it would then be:

```
Verified     -1 Fails   John Doe
```

instead of

```
Verified     -1   John Doe
```

I'm using Gerrit 2.14.3 and I can not find any settings in the configuration to add this text.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no configuration for that.

Comment: That was sad! I have added a feature request for this: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=8736